# Руссификация WooCommerce вызывает ошибку WordPress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Как мне руссифицировать плагин без потери работоспособности сайта?
Устанавливаю через админку свежий плагин WooCommerce для WordPress — всё работает нормально, только на английском. Обновляю перевод — перестаёт отображаться библиотека медиафайлов, не добавляется превью товаров.

Методом проб выяснил, что ошибка появляется после добавления файла

> wp-content/languages/plugins/woocommerce-ru_RU.mo

и исчезает после его удаления. Вместе с переводом на русский.

Comment: Гипотеза - незакрытые html-теги или лишние кавычки. Либо в русификации, либо в коде, который её использует. Видимо, как раз в части, взаимодействующей с изображениями. Что показывает браузер, если для страницы с отсутствующими превью нажать "Показать код страницы"?

Comment: Прошу прощения ввел в заблуждение: новые превьюшки не добавляются. Старые показываются нормально.
При открытии из админпанели библиотеки медиафайлов  в консоль выводятся ошибки:`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)` `load-scripts.php?c=1&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,plupload&ver=4.5.2:4 POST http://eikuzora.valuehost.ru/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 500 (Internal Server Error)`

Comment: Как найти проблемный участок файла woocommerce-ru_RU.po - там больше 9000 строк?
Проблема точно не в коде, отвечающем за русификацию - скачал плагин woocommerce saphali, взял из него файлы woocommerce-ru_RU.mo и .po, разместил их в папку для языков. Изменения вступают в силу, языки заменяются, ошибок не происходит.

Comment: 1) Не хватает идеи, как сузить поле поиска. Можете выложить два html-кода страницы - с русским переводом и без него? 2) Погуглил [wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 500](https://goo.gl/lDrzIE). Увидел несколько предложений проверить права доступа. У файлов русского перевода они такие же как у файлов английского языка? 3) Еще один совет из Сети - проверить журнал ошибок сервера.

Comment: Проблему как будто бы решил, но немного топорно. В чем на самом деле было причина?
Лог ошибок сервера заполнен сообщениями типа: 
`79.164.158.20 eikuzora.valuehost.ru - [12/May/2016:18:15:53 +0300] "GET /wp-content/themes/mystile%20child/img/search32.jpg HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "http://eikuzora.valuehost.ru/wp-content/themes/mystile%20child/style.css" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:46.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/46.0"
`

Answer (score 2):

Проблему исправил так: нашел аналогичный файл woocommerce-ru_RU.mo из другого плагина, подставил его на место первого. Убедился что перевод хоть и не полностью, но осуществился. Потом кусками стал добавлять наполнение из нерабочего файла в рабочий, компилируя каждый кусок с помощью программы poedit. Ошибка происходит где-то на последних 2000 строк файла, на участке между переводами названий Кастельона и Шариатпура. Надеюсь что никто из пользователей сайта не будет заказывать доставку туда.

Answer (score 0):

Русский лангпак можно скачать: https://translate.wordpress.org/projects/wp-plugins/woocommerce/stable/ru/default
Хотя он и сам подтянется.